# wxPython ListCtrl item. SetBackgroundColour doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, listctrl

I'm using Python3, wxPython 4 on MacBook Air M1, macOS Big Sur.
I found the SetBackgroundColour method doesn't work, (but when I call item.SetText("888"), the text has been successfully updated )
Does anyone know the reason?
Thanks!

```
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl  as  listmix

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("white")

        rows = [("Tom", "11"),
                ("Ede", "11"),
                ("Jerry", "10")
                ]
        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.list_ctrl.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255,246,189,255))
        self.list_ctrl.SetTextColour('black')
        
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Col1")  
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Col2")  # Revenue this Q than last Q 

        
        index = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, row[0])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 1, row[1])

            if int(row[1]) <= 10: #current PE is 50% down than 52w high
                item = self.list_ctrl.GetItem(1,1)
                item.SetText("888") # successfully changed
                item.SetBackgroundColour('Blue') #not changed
                self.list_ctrl.SetItem(item)

                print(item.GetText())
                print(item.GetBackgroundColour())

            index += 1
        
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,"test")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've revisited this because your code does some fiddling about, which I didn't take into consideration.
I've also addressed the Deprecation warnings you would have been getting.
In short, access the item via the `ListCtrl` and use the `index`.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl  as  listmix

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("white")

        rows = [("Tom", "10"),
                ("Ede", "11"),
                ("Jerry", "12"),
                ("Rolf", "10"),
                ("Neo", "12")
                ]
        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.list_ctrl.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255,246,189,255))
        self.list_ctrl.SetTextColour('black')
        
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Col1")  
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Col2")  # Revenue this Q than last Q 

        
        index = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.list_ctrl.InsertItem(index, row[0])
            self.list_ctrl.SetItem(index, 1, row[1])

            if int(row[1]) <= 10: #current PE is 50% down than 52w high
                self.list_ctrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(index, 'LightGreen')

            index += 1
        
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,"test")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rolf! can you do me a favor, do you know how to set only one cell background color?

Comment: your code doesn't take effect on my machine, I kinda believe this is because I'm using MacOS, and you are using Ubuntu.

Comment: @NeoLin I believe that when you set a colour on a listrctrl row, it applies it to the whole row. If you access the item, you set a colour and it reports back that colour but it doesn't display. The listctrl must be overriding it.

Comment: Okay, thank you Rolf!